# Run Python in excel files via VBA when the files are in different locations

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

by using the features provided by `xlwings` (http://docs.xlwings.org/en/v0.7.2/vba.html) I can easily run python routines from within the xls and if the file I am about to call does not have any dependencies that are in an "upper" level of directiories within in the project, all is well. if not, it does not work.

```
myProject
    |__ Exposures
        |__ XLS_1.xlsx
        |__ exec_file_for_XLS_1.py
    |__ Routines
        |__ main_routines.py

    XLS_2.xlsx
    exec_file_for_XLS_2.py

# for explanatory purposes
exec_file_for_XLS_1.py = exec_file_for_XLS_2.py
XLS_1.xlsx = XLS_2.xlsx

inside exec_file_for_XLS_1 calls:
    import Routines.main_routines
```

so, If I call `exec_file_for_XLS_1.py` from `XLS_1.xlsx`, I get an error because the `xlwings` module can't search in the entrie project whereas if I call `exec_file_for_XLS2.py` from `XLS_2.xlsx` it works because it searches for folders in the "lower" levels of the project

my question is: aside from moving the excel (and its `.py` execution file) to the top level (not feasible in my case), what can I do to work around such issue?

do newer versions (mine is `0.7.2`) solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the directory that python can't reach to your `PYTHONPATH` in the VBA settings, see http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/vba.html#settings.

Comment: I saw that, but I thought it was only referring to the place where the python interpreter was to be found, not also the searchable folders. i'll look into it right away